# Difference between 'a' and 'w' flag in php fopen

Tags: php

I am trying in create a file in php. The directory exists, but the file does not exist.

I tried using `fopen` with the 'r' flag but it throws an error.

`failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I checked for file permissions.
I switched to using the 'a' flag and it works.

```
$file = fopen('output/readme.txt', 'a');
fwrite($file, 'some text to input');
fclose($file);
```

From the [php manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), both 'w' and 'a' flags seem to do the same thing.

- Open a file for write only
- Create a file if not exists

Is there a difference between the two flags? What could be causing the error?

EDIT: I tried it again, this time both 'w' and 'a' flags worked without throwing any errors. I may have unknowingly used the wrong flag. But thanks for clarifying the file pointer. I clearly overlooked that difference.

Comment: Hm, from that page: "_place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length_" vs "_place the file pointer at the end of the file_"

Comment: If you're really using the `r` flag then that error would be expected if the file doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the manual carefully:

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer **at the beginning** of the file and **truncate the file** to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer **at the end** of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

So basically *w* will empty the file, *a* will append to it.